# Is there a case where delegate syntax is preferred over lambda expression for anonymous methods?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, delegates, lambda, anonymous-methods

With the advent of new features like lambda expressions (inline code), does it mean we dont have to use delegates or anonymous methods anymore? In almost all the samples I have seen, it is for rewriting using the new syntax.

Any place where we still have to use delegates and lambda expressions won't work?

Comment: Also see [whats-the-difference-between-anonymous-methods-and-lambda-expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208381/whats-the-difference-between-anonymous-methods-c-2-0-and-lambda-expressions) for general differences.

Answer (score 27):

Yes there are places where directly using anonymous delegates and lambda expressions won't work.

If a method takes an untyped Delegate then the compiler doesn't know what to resolve the anonymous delegate/lambda expression to and you will get a compiler error.

```
public static void Invoke(Delegate d)
{
  d.DynamicInvoke();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // fails
  Invoke(() => Console.WriteLine("Test"));

  // works
  Invoke(new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Test")));

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The failing line of code will get the compiler error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type".

Comment: I think the questioner is asking about `delegate` keyword being obsolete, in favour of newer lambda based syntax. She groups "anonymous methods and delegates" together.

Answer (score 8):

lambda is shortcut for anonymous delegate, but you will always be using delegates. the delegate specifies the methods signature. you can just do this:

```
 delegate(int i) { Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()) }
```

can be replaced with

```
f => Console.WriteLine(f.ToString())
```

Answer (score 7):

Lambda expression is not (and was not meant to be) a silver bullet that would replace (hide) delegates. It is great with small local things like:

```
List<string> names = GetNames();
names.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

1. it makes code more readable thus simple to understand.
2. It makes code shorter thus less work for us ;)

On the other hand it is very simple to misuse them. Long or/and complex lambda expressions are tending to be:

1. Hard to understand for new developers
2. Less object oriented
3. Much harder to read

So “does it mean we don’t have to use delegates or anonymous methods anymore?” No – use Lambda expression where you win time/readability otherwise consider using delegates.

Comment: WOW!!! I never thout about this one! Is there way to do predicate too i.e. names.Where(!string.IsNullOrEmpty)); ? I tried and it doesn't work for me.
Oops! If I remove the ! operand it does work, why??? I even tried puting it in parentheses but it can't invoke it altogether, is there a way?
We are actually trying to convert string.IsNullOrEmpty to string.IsNotNullOrEmpty...

Answer (score 5):

One *not so big* advantage for the older `delegate` syntax is that you need not specify the parameters if you dont use it in the method body. From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx)

> There is one case in which an anonymous method provides functionality
>   not found in lambda expressions. Anonymous methods enable you to omit
>   the parameter list. This means that an anonymous method can be
>   converted to delegates with a variety of signatures. This is not
>   possible with lambda expressions.

For example you can do:

```
Action<int> a = delegate { }; //takes 1 argument, but not specified on the RHS
```

While this fails:

```
Action<int> a = => { }; //omitted parameter, doesnt compile.
```

This technique mostly comes handy when writing event-handlers, like:

```
button.onClicked += delegate { Console.WriteLine("clicked"); };
```

This is not a *strong* advantage. It's better to adopt the newer syntax always imho.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a use case since early morning today as to why would I specify an argument in a method signature but not use it in the method body :P. Event-handlers seems like an example but still _1_. The omission of parameters adds to confusion. _2_. Tomorrow if I fall into the need of using either of `object sender, EventArgs e` parameters then the developer should be aware of this specific compiler trick which isn't so obvious. For me it is a thumbs down from a feature stand-point just to save two words of typing. I strongly agree with you on - _This is not a strong advantage_

Answer (score 4):

Delegate have two meanings in C#.

The keyword `delegate` can be used to define a function signature type. This is usually used when defininge the signature of higher-order functions, i.e. functions that take other functions as arguments. This use of delegate is still relevant.

The `delegate` keyword can also be used to define an inline anonymous function. In the case where the function is just a single expression, the lambda syntax is a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Lambda expressions are just "syntactic sugar", the compiler will generate appropriate delegates for you. You can investigate this by using Lutz Roeder's Reflector.

Comment: Actually lambda expressions are a bit more than syntactic sugar since they can be compiled into an expression tree and manipulated.

Answer (score 3):

Lamda's are just syntactic sugar for delegates, they are not just inline, you can do the following:

```
s.Find(a =>
{
    if (a.StartsWith("H"))
        return a.Equals("HI");
    else
        return !a.Equals("FOO");
});
```

And delegates are still used when defining events, or when you have lots of arguments and want to actually strongly type the method being called.