# how come BinaryFormatter can serialize an Action<> but Json.net cannot

Tags: c#, json.net

Trying to serialize/deserialize an Action<>.

Try #1 naive by me

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myAction);
...
JsonConvert.Deserialize<Action>(json);
```

Deserialize fails saying it cannot serialize Action.

Try #2

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Action>(ctx.SerializedJob, new JsonSerializerSettings {ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor });
```

Same(ish) failure.

Try # 3
Then I found http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/04/serializing-continuations.html

This uses BinaryFormatter. I dropped this in (base64 encoding the binary to a string). Worked perfectly first time.

Try #4

I then found

https://github.com/DevrexLabs/Modules.JsonNetFormatter

Which is an IFormatter module for json.net. Wired that in, same failure - cannot deserialize.

So how come BinaryFormatter can do it but Json.net cannot?

EDIT:

The general reply is - "thats the most stupid thing to want to do". Let me show what I am trying to do

```
MyJobSystem.AddJob(ctx=>
{
   // code to do
   // ......
}, DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromDays(2));
```

Ie - execute this lambda in 2 days time.

This works fine for me. Using BinaryFormatter. I was curious about why one serializing infrastructure could do it but the other could not. They both seem to have the same rules about what can and cannot be processed

Comment: Why would you even want to serialize an action? What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: If it's just out of curiosity how BinaryFormatter does it, you can probably find out by reading through the [Reference Implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryobjectwriter.cs,2948255041cfcd43).

Comment: And here is [the relevant part of Json.Net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L66)

Comment: I would expect the result to be something I can deserialize and execute later. I have a job scheduling system that I can pass either a Type, and instance or an Action to. This now works using the BinaryFormatter sample I pointed at

Comment: I tried reading the reference source, which is what I would always do. But its an extremely convoluted code base.

Comment: Actions are delegates. It wouldn't make any sense to serialize them. You would basically just be left with a function pointer that could point to who knows what when you deserialize it again.

Comment: And why it should be able to? Json.NET is completely different from BinaryFormatter, and serializing delegates is certainly far out of use case for json.net. If you need - serialize with binary formatter, convert to base64 and store that in json together with other info you need. Though I'd better reconsider doing this (serializing delegates).

Comment: And the next step would be serialize in c#, then deserialize and execute in java :)

Comment: @Evk - thats exactly what I am doing, works perfectly

Comment: @Eser - I am doing this to persist and reload into the same app, Not to pass between systems.

Comment: *"thats the most stupid thing to want to do"* Close, but not quite. I'd rather call it *risky* and *probably* unrelyable in some cases. Try to serialize this action for example `int x = 1; Action a = new Action(()=>{Debug.WriteLine(x);});`. That won't work.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - you are correct. Capture doesnt work. My use cases dont need it

Comment: `why one serializing infrastructure could do it but the other could not.` Because every serialization codes handle the process their way(see also xml, protobuf, yaml etc). All you need  is writing a non-anonymous method and serialize(store) the method name and parameters.... When execution is needed, you have all the info you need

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The reason** that `BinaryFormatter` is (sometimes) able to round-trip an `Action<T>` is that such delegates are marked as [`[Serializable]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and implement [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, just because the delegate itself is marked as serializable doesn't mean that its members can be serialized successfully.  In testing, I was able to serialize the following delegate:

```
Action<int> a1 = (a) => Console.WriteLine(a);
```

But attempting to serialize the following threw a `SerializationException`:

```
int i = 0;
Action<int> a2 = (a) => i = i + a;
```

The captured variable `i` apparently is placed in a non-serializable compiler-generated class thereby preventing binary serialization of the delegate from succeeding.

On the other hand, Json.NET is unable to round-trip an `Action<T>` despite [supporting `ISerializable`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable) because it does not provide support for serialization proxies configured via [`SerializationInfo.SetType(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.settype(v=vs.110).aspx).  We can confirm that `Action<T>` is using this mechanism with the following code:

```
var iSerializable = a1 as ISerializable;
if (iSerializable != null)
{
    var info = new SerializationInfo(a1.GetType(), new FormatterConverter());
    var initialFullTypeName = info.FullTypeName;
    iSerializable.GetObjectData(info, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All));
    Console.WriteLine("Initial FullTypeName = \"{0}\", final FullTypeName = \"{1}\".", initialFullTypeName, info.FullTypeName);
    var enumerator = info.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   Name = {0}, objectType = {1}, value = {2}.", enumerator.Name, enumerator.ObjectType, enumerator.Value);
    }
}
```

When run, it outputs:

```
Initial FullTypeName = "System.Action`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]", final FullTypeName = "System.DelegateSerializationHolder".
   Name = Delegate, objectType = System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry, value = System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry.
   Name = method0, objectType = System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo, value = Void <Test>b__0(Int32).
```

Notice that `FullTypeName` has changed to [`System.DelegateSerializationHolder`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegateserializationholder.cs)?  That's the proxy, and it's not supported by Json.NET.

This begs the question, **just what is written out when a delegate is serialized?**  To determine this we can configure Json.NET to serialize `Action<T>` similarly to how `BinaryFormatter` would by setting

- [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm)
- [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableInterface = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableInterface.htm)
- [`JsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_TypeNameHandling.htm)

If I serialize `a1` using these settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        IgnoreSerializableInterface = false,
        IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false,
    },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a1, settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Then the following JSON is generated:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Action`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
  "Delegate": {
    "$type": "System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry, mscorlib",
    "type": "System.Action`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
    "assembly": "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "target": null,
    "targetTypeAssembly": "Tile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "targetTypeName": "Question49138328.TestClass",
    "methodName": "<Test>b__0",
    "delegateEntry": null
  },
  "method0": {
    "$type": "System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo, mscorlib",
    "Name": "<Test>b__0",
    "AssemblyName": "Tile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "ClassName": "Question49138328.TestClass",
    "Signature": "Void <Test>b__0(Int32)",
    "MemberType": 8,
    "GenericArguments": null
  }
}
```

The replacement `FullTypeName` is not included but everything else is.  And as you can see, it's not actually storing the IL instructions of the delegate; it's storing the full signature of the method(s) to call, including the hidden, compiler-generated method name `<Test>b__0` mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709299).  You can see the hidden method name yourself just by printing `a1.Method.Name`.

Incidentally, to confirm that Json.NET is really saving the same member data as `BinaryFormatter`, you can serialize `a1` to binary and print any embedded ASCII strings as follows:

```
var binary = BinaryFormatterHelper.ToBinary(a1);
var s = Regex.Replace(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(binary), @"[^\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(s);
Assert.IsTrue(s.Contains(a1.Method.Name)); // Always passes
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static partial class BinaryFormatterHelper
{
    public static byte[] ToBinary<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Doing so results in the following string:

```
????"System.DelegateSerializationHolderDelegatemethod00System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry/System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolder0System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntrytypeassemblytargettargetTypeAssemblytargetTypeNamemethodNamedelegateEntry0System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntrylSystem.Action`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]Kmscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;Tile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullQuestion49138328.TestClass<Test>b__0/System.Reflection.MemberInfoSerializationHolderNameAssemblyNameClassNameSignatureMemberTypeGenericArgumentsSystem.Type[]Void <Test>b__0(Int32)
```

And the assert never fires, indicating that the compiler-generated method name `<Test>b__0` is indeed present in the binary also.

**Now, here's the scary part**.  If I modify my c# source code to create another `Action<T>` before `a1`, like so:

```
// I inserted this before a1 and then recompiled: 
Action<int> a0 = (a) => Debug.WriteLine(a);

Action<int> a1 = (a) => Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Then re-build and re-run, *`a1.Method.Name` changes to `<Test>b__1`*:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Action`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
  "Delegate": {
    "$type": "System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry, mscorlib",
    "type": "System.Action`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
    "assembly": "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "target": null,
    "targetTypeAssembly": "Tile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "targetTypeName": "Question49138328.TestClass",
    "methodName": "<Test>b__1",
    "delegateEntry": null
  },
  "method0": {
    "$type": "System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo, mscorlib",
    "Name": "<Test>b__1",
    "AssemblyName": "Tile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "ClassName": "Question49138328.TestClass",
    "Signature": "Void <Test>b__1(Int32)",
    "MemberType": 8,
    "GenericArguments": null
  }
}
```

Now if I deserialize binary data for `a1` saved from the earlier version, it comes back as `a0`!  Thus, adding another delegate somewhere in your code base, or otherwise refactoring your code in an apparently harmless way, may cause previously serialized delegate data to be corrupt and fail or even ***possibly execute the wrong method when deserialized into the new version of your software***.  Further, this is unlikely to be fixable other than by reverting all changes out of your code and never making such changes again.

**To sum up**, we have found that serialized delegate information is incredibly fragile to seemingly-unrelated changes in one's code base.  I would strongly recommend against persisting delegates through serialization with either `BinaryFormatter` or Json.NET.  Instead, consider maintaining a table of named delegates and serializing the names, or following the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and serialize command objects.

Comment: excellent answer - thank you very much. So I just needed to add a couple of extra flags to json.net deserializer

Comment: In your last example delegate data is much worse than meaningless or invalid. It now points to _another_ method, because now `a0` is `<Test>b__0`.

Comment: @Evk - yes that's true.  Maybe I could express it more strongly.