# How does anonymous methods omit parameter list?

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function, anonymous-methods

I was reading this in the MSDN documentation on [Anonymous Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx), but I do not understand the part about omitting the parameter list. It says:

> There is one case in which an anonymous method provides functionality
>   not found in lambda expressions. Anonymous methods enable you to omit
>   the parameter list. This means that an anonymous method can be
>   converted to delegates with a variety of signatures. This is not
>   possible with lambda expressions.

Could you provide an example of ommiting a parameter list for an anonymous method?

Comment: See a lot of other threads, fpr example [delegate keyword vs. lambda notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299703/) and all the threads linked to it.

Comment: I have edited the q and voted to reopen it. I think it's clear now. But for an answer, you can [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24552532/661933)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505850/can-i-ignore-delegate-parameters-with-lambda-syntax/505892#505892

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you confused about *lambda expressions* and *anonymous methods*. What you need to understand is that lambda expressions are just *syntantic sugars*.For example, you can create an anonymous method that takes 2 integer parameter and returns an `integer` like this:

```
Func<int, int, int> func = delegate(int x, int y)
                           {
                                return x + y;
                           };
```

Using lambda syntax you can shorten that statement into this:

```
Func<int, int, int> func2 = (x,y) => x + y;
```

Also you don't really need to pass any argument to a lambda statement.For example this is completely valid:

```
Action act = () => Console.WriteLine("hello world");
```

So as a result, lambda expressions allows you to create *anonymous methods* with *less* code and they don't have any disadvantages as compared to anonymous methods because they are completely different things.You are comparing *apples* with *oranges*.

Comment: But the old C# 2-style anonymous method can leave out all the parameters entirely, like for the zero "function" of two arguments, it could be `Func<int, int, int> funcZero = delegate { return 0; };`. With a lambda syntax you have to give both parameters (even if you don't use them), but their types can be inferred, so `Func<int, int, int> funcZero = (x, y) => 0;`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen which is what OP is asking. You could have provided an answer!

Comment: The answer is not an answer, but the comment is.