# Parameterless anonymous method can be assigned to parametered delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-function, anonymous-methods

```
class Program{
      static void Main(){
         test11 jhbee = Program.test;  //error
         test11 yep = delegate {  };   //no error

      }
   static void test() { }
}

delegate void test11(int r);
```

So I have the delegate `test11` which returns void and takes 1 parameter.
whn I try to assign a *parameterless* method to an instance of `test11`, the compiler, obviously issues an error but when I assign a *parameterless* **anonymous** method to an instance of `test11`, no error is issued.
I mean, I can see that there is no obstacle for it to work but can you please tell me why is this so? Is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator):

> When you use the delegate operator, you might omit the parameter list. If you do that, the created anonymous method can be converted to a delegate type with any list of parameters

So while it appears that way, the created anonymous method is not really parameterless - its parameter list has just not been defined.

As for the reason why this is an option, [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24552532/5792352) might help explain it.